# rspec controller put update test not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I am stuck on a rspec test that is testing a update method in my controller.  I am getting a routing error. Hoping someone smarter than I can help.  I have googled and read many post on this site, but none have turned on the light-bulb in my head.

Note: this works when finding and updating a record via the browser.  Just cannot figure out the test for it.

My Route for this controller update method:

```
PUT    /admins/project_codes/:id(.:format)          admins/project_codes#update
```

My controller update method:

```
def update
  @project_code = ProjectCode.find(params[:project_code][:id])
  if @project_code.update_attributes(params[:project_code])
    redirect_to(:action => :show, :id => params[:project_code][:id])
  else
    redirect_to(:action => :edit, :id => params[:project_code][:id], :notice => "Your record for #{params[:project_code][:code]} could not be updated at this time.")
  end
end
```

The edit form is using name="project_code[...]" for fields: i.e:

```
<input id="project_code_code" name="project_code[code]" size="10" type="text" value="F-UZBEKIST" /
```

So, in my test, I need create a record, then update a field and pass it to my update method.  I'm trying to create the params[:project_code] to pass to the method.

spec:

```
describe "PUT #update" do
  it "updates with valid name change" do
    code = FactoryGirl.create(:project_code)
    code.name = "new-name"
    put :update, :project_code => code.attributes
    ...
  end
end
```

My error:

```
1) Admins::ProjectCodesController PUT #update updates with valid name change
 Failure/Error: put 'update', :project_code => code.attributes
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:project_code=>{"id"=>"10375", "code"=>"ABCDEFG", "name"=>"new-name", "update_by"=>"jdc44", "created_at"=>"2015-10-07 13:22:31 -0400", "updated_at"=>"2015-10-07 13:22:31 -0400"}, :controller=>"admins/project_codes", :action=>"update"}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `PUT /admins/project_codes/:id(.:format)` requires an `:id` parameter in the url, try sending the following:

```
put :update, :id => code.id, :project_code => code.attributes
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  That is it.  Odd the form does not have a "plain old" name="id" field.  name="project_code[id]" is there.  Now I get a >> "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: id, created_at, updated_at".  But, I've seen those before.  THANK YOU

Comment: @JohnCowan I'm glad I could help. If you think that my answer solves your problem, please, consider accepting and upvoting it. You can read more about the process here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. Thanks!